# Is there a contradiction at the top of this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Applying kirchhoff's second law to the first loop, the current in the upper branch remains determined and is $2.4$ A to the right (if $i$ is to the right then $-10i + 24 = 0$). Then the current in the upper branch of the second loop must be $8 + 6 + 2.4 = 16.4$ A to the right. But how can it be? Using kirchhoff's second law with the second loop it is found that the current in the upper branch must be $17.6$ A to the left (if $i$ is to the right then $-5i - 88 = 0$). All this assuming current generator have negligible resistance. I'm doing some stupid mistake that I can't see.

Comment: Yours calculations are fine, I think. The values given might me erroneous. What are you supposed to find in this question?

Comment: @ShivamSinghAswal It is asked $V$ in the left. But if the circuit is meaningless, if current generator cannot do their job, I wonder if the question is meaningfull.

Comment: Well that's right. The question itself is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what is asked is V on the left, you may assume an ideal voltmeter drawing zero current. Then, your circuit is a big loop producing a voltage but zero current. The big loop is composed of 5 things in series: three loops and two resistors. Because they are in series, their voltages add, but their through currents are zero.

There's no current through the 13Ω and 9Ω resistors. They contribute nothing to the voltage. So, all you have to do is analyze each loop separately. Figure out what the current is in each current loop, figure out what voltage that produces across their terminals. The other loop is easier.

The rest is left to the student.

Comment: Indeed, there's no contradiction because the voltmeter at the left draws no current. The only currents flowing are in the closed loops. So calculate them independently and then add up the voltage drops.

Comment: If I must assume that in the left can't go current, then all is like the two current generator are 84 V to right and 128 V to left. This simply gives that down left the potential is 35 V larger than up left. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit may be feasible if the circles represent power supplies (constant current or voltage) rather than meter readings.

Answer (score 0):

Loop analysis necessitates a singe value of loop current. Just like node analysis necessitates a single value of node voltage. In your case, you are getting two different values of current in each branch of each loop instead of one loop current. In reality the current leaving the bottom branch of each loop must enter the top branch so that no current flows between the two loops.

I believe the root of the inconsistency is assuming two ideal current sources. This gives you two different values for a single loop current. Real current sources have impedance (resistance) in parallel. If you include resistors in parallel with the two current sources you will have no inconsistency.

A similar inconsistency results when attempting to connect two ideal voltage sources with different emfs in parallel, giving you two different values of voltage for a single point. Real voltage sources have impedance (resistance) in series.

I have replicated your circuit below, adding resistors in parallel with the current sources and a resistor in series with the voltage source so that they represent actual current and voltage sources.

Note that adding the resistors for the current generators does not alter the value of the current. But there is now a voltage drop across the generator resistances in the bottom branches equal to the current generator times the resistance.  The voltage drop across $R_1$ is $6R_1$ and across $R_2$ is $8R_2$. Each current generator and its parallel resistance are themselves loops.

The same current is now in the bottom and top branches of each loop, so there is no current flowing between the loops. The loops are independent of each other because they do not have any circuit elements in common.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: It looks impossibile, with that resistances, to put current generator with negligible resistances with an appropriate emf to generate current of 6 A and 8 A in that way. So, I suppose (looking to your answer), to solve a such circuit we *can't* ignore the internal resistance of current source. We must call R the unknown resistance of al least one of the 2 current generator, before going on with the analysis of the circuit. This is the way when we found a contradiction? @Bob D

Comment: That is what I'm saying. With any resistor in parallel with the current sources you will find that all the current leaving the bottom branch of each loop enters the top branch of each loop, with no current flowing between the loops. I will revise my answer to elaborate.

Comment: See my update. Hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding your first statement, it appears you are thinking the resistance of the current generator is in series. It is not. It is in parallel, as i indicated in my answer.

Comment: But if current generator resistance is assumed negligible, isn't the same if It is in serie or in parallel to its emf generator (the self adjusting emf generator of the current generator)? If It is not negligible, and it is an unknown to be determinated, wouldn't It be useless to put this resistance in parallel to the Ideal zero resistance emf generator? All the current would go throug the generator.

Comment: I'm assuming current generator can be thinked as a resistance (usually negligible but not in that case) + a zero resistance emf generator that adjust its emf to generate the specific current. But i can't understand why the resistance must be put in parallel.

Comment: I think your confused about current generators. I will include a diagram.

Comment: See update (hopefully the last)

Comment: I thank you so much.  anyway I solved with another way.

Comment: OK there are often more than one way to solve a problem.